# Incorrect %1 parameter when a file or folder that has an & (ampersand) or a ^ (caret), and no space in its full name is dropped onto a batch file

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop, caret, ampersand

Is there a solution to: `The %1 parameter is incorrect` when a file or folder that has an `&` (ampersand) or a `^` (caret), and no space in its full name is dropped onto a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

After running into this problem myself, I am posting a solution for review and to give back for all I have learned from ss64.com and stackoverflow.com – Thank you!

From my testing, the enclosed batch file works for all but the command line character limitation.

Solution for & and ^:

Regarding the %1 parameter:
Drops with spaces in them are workable because a space auto invokes surrounding double quotation marks which escape all special characters within that quoted string.
Ampersands and carets require the same process that spaces receive but that process is not invoked for them.

A workaround solution is to use and modify %cmdcmdline% so that it provides surrounding double quotation marks for each dropped file and folder.  This also results in a consistent formatting of the parameters which simplifies processing.
The workaround is shown in the accompanying batch file.

Of equal importance to the workaround, is the control and predictability of double quotation marks:
While the workaround is straightforward,  the implementation and effects of double quotation marks needs to be understood in order to prevent them from causing errors throughout the batch file.
One pair of surrounding double quotation marks escapes all special characters within that quoted string.
Two pairs of surrounding double quotation marks are functionally the same as no double quotation marks, which results in nothing being escaped and any special characters remain active (batch files do not have a left or a right quotation mark -- open quote is closed by the very next unassigned quotation mark).

When possible, avoid double quotes embedded in parameters and variables.
Negate embedded double quotes with "%~1" or strip them by using set "var=%var:"=%"
Unless necessary, use set "var=value" rather than set var="value"

In the enclosed batch file the protective double quotation marks are:
Internal in !params! during preprocessing, 
Consumed in a For Command, 
Kept external for "%_Dropped%" during processing

This work is based on and gratefully acknowledged to jeb's strategy and code at:
https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1168
"dragdrop file named with ampersand problem" - 13 Jan 2011 15:07
Also, thank you allal for your well asked questions years before I had them.

P.S. I wrote here what I needed to know before this started.

Side note: (there may be other uses for this) echoing a single digit to a text file failed for me until () were added, try:
echo 9>> con & (echo 9)>> con

```
::  Code ...   Stable_Params.bat

@prompt $g 
@if "%~1"=="" echo  This batch file requires that at least one file or folder is dropped onto it - & echo  Press any key to exit . . .& pause > nul & exit
@set drop__count=0
@set exist_count=0
@echo  ---  %%cmdcmdline%% is ...   (with no double quote control, special characters can cause errors in this command)
@echo %cmdcmdline%
goto Preproc_Params


=== Instructions:
Drop files and folders with names that contain ampersands or carets, and with and without spaces in them, onto this batch file.
Also, for media root drops: drop one and multiple drive letters onto this batch file.

=== Passes the cartoon swear word folder name test:  (This test's failures prompted this solution)
To see a failure: in the Test_Loop remove the @rem from either of the rem'd out lines, and drop onto this batch file a folder with this name...  !@#$+~%(-^&`,;)

=== To ensure there are double quotes surrounding each drop to a batch file, and then processing them:
(1) Enable Delayed Expansion to allow the %~d1 parameter within !! and for containing special characters.
(2) set params equal to the parameters by replacing the start of !cmdcmdline! through its first "<space> with "
(3) strip all double quotes within !params! while setting one pair of surrounding double quotes into !params!
(4) for multiple media root drops (drive letters): insert double quotes into !params! by replacing \<space> with \"<space>"
(5) for multiple file/folder drops: insert double quotes into !params! by replacing <space><drive:> with "<space>"<drive:>
(6) Disable Delayed Expansion so drops with an ! (exclamation mark) in their full name are workable.
(7) For Command to consume the quotes; parse the parameters, assign them to a variable, and process them in a called loop.
(8) During processing surround "%_Dropped%" with one pair of double quotes to disable the activation of special characters.


:Preproc_Params
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@set "params=!cmdcmdline:*" ="!"
@set params="!params:"=!"
@set "params=!params:\ =\" "!"
@set "params=!params: %~d1=" "%~d1!"
@setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

@echo.
@echo  ---  double quote adjusted %%params%% with the start of %%cmdcmdline%% through its first "<space> replaced with "
@echo %params%

:: Split the parameters on spaces but respect and consume the quotes
@for %%G in (%params%) do (set "_Dropped=%%~G" & set /a "drop__count+=1" & call :Test_Loop)
goto TestLoop_Done


:Test_Loop
@if exist "%_Dropped%" (set /a "exist_count+=1") & (echo "%%_Dropped%%" is "%_Dropped%")
@if not exist "%_Dropped%" (echo "%_Dropped%"   does not exist, or it is drive letter with no media)

:: When not rem'd out, the following line with certain drops will cause a failure and possibly a window exit
@rem @(echo  %%_Dropped%%  is  %_Dropped%)

:: A second pair of surrounding double quotes acts the same as no quotes -- open quote is closed by the next quotation mark
@rem @(echo  ""%%_Dropped%%""  is  ""%_Dropped%"")

@exit /b


:TestLoop_Done
@echo.
@(echo   %%drop__count%%  is__  %drop__count%)
@(echo   %%exist_count%%  is__  %exist_count%)
@echo.
@echo   Press any key to exit . . . & pause > nul

::  Code end  ---
```